# SQLite Create Table Query does not create a table

Tags: database, sqlite, web-sql

This simple sqlite query:

```
CREATE TABLE customers 
(
    id INT(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    name VARCHAR(255),  
    email VARCHAR(255),  
    password VARCHAR(255), 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

is not working.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct syntax for the definition of the table:

```
CREATE TABLE customers ( 
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT 
  name TEXT,  
  email TEXT,  
  password TEXT
);
```

SQLite does not support `AUTOINCREMENT` when the column's data type is other than `INTEGER` and the column is not the `PRIMARY KEY` of the table.
Also there are no `int(255)` and `VARCHAR` [data types in SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) (although you can use it in the `CREATE TABLE` statement). Use `TEXT` instead of `VARCHAR`.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=ff51ef8d442d58944ff7038cf86f62ae).

Answer (score 0):

SQL lite doesn't support cahrchar or auto increment (at least not without rowid

see [manual](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html)

> ```
> CREATE TABLE t(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC, name TEXT , email TEXT ,  password TEXT);
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO t (name,email, password) VALUES ('abc','bcd','efg')
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO t (name,email, password) VALUES ('abc2','bcd2','efg2')
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM t;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name | email | password
> -: | :--- | :---- | :-------
>  1 | abc  | bcd   | efg     
>  2 | abc2 | bcd2  | efg2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=c8090ae6210177f72a0891f6e4e65885)*

Comment: SQLite supports AUTOINCREMENT: https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html

Comment: @torpqas dbfiddlw throws an error if you don't add without rowid

Comment: What error? Check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=7d58756edaaae7b58146f591febe0258

Comment: you don't need autoincrement as you see in my answer, iz follows the officla documentation as well

Comment: Read the documentation carefully. When AUTOINCREMENT is used the values of the rowids are not reused after deletions as they could be when it is not used. The behavior is not the same.